# Server Side equalant WL.SecurityUtils.keygen

Tags: worklight-adapters, worklight-server, worklight-security

can i use WL.SecurityUtils.keygen on server side ?
Is there any JS API is available for worklight Server side similar to  WL.SecurityUtils.keygen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Such API does not exist, the API is available only on the client-side.
Feature requests can be sent through here: https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/help/